# Spring OAuth Library for web application

Tags: java, spring, oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I am trying to build an web application with oauth authentication. Which is the best suitable library between brick red social auth and spring social? Please suggest me pros and cons of the two.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Spring Social and Red Social Auth. Both are good Libraries and liked Spring Social a lot as it has lot of powerful features. Please visit spring social github page and follow the examples.